# How to merge multiple vertices to each other and keep uv?

Tags: uv, vertices

I'm having troubles with the seams of my .obj jeans on blender.

First of all, I added some edges like this:

[image]

Now, what I want to do, is merging each vertices to the one beside, like this:

[image]

The result is exactly what I want, but this take so much time.
Is it possible to select multiple vertices of each part of the pants and merge them just in one click, instead of do that with every single vertice ? Of course, the most important, is that I want to keep the uv exactly the same when merging.

I tried the remove doubles method and it didn't worked. Also tried the Bridge Edges loops method and I got this message:
[image]

(one time the Bridge Edges Loops tools worked, but this changed my uv and did my objects have a weird white shadow on the merging line)

Comment: W > Remove Doubles and if vertices aren't perfectly overlapping you can tweak Merge distance (Tool shelf or after pressing F6).

Comment: @LukeD And it worked !! I didn't know the Merge distance tool !
I feel a little silly because it was so simple ... Thank you so much !

Comment: I don't get how Bridge Edge Loops can help here, if used on selected geometry on the last screenshot it will create internal faces which can cause bad shading and artifacts while using Subsurf (and other modifiers). Remove doubles can corrupt some UV islands, depending on the case. Any geometry removal / adding will change UV map, so if you want to avoid that use either LoopCut, removing doubles, knife and merging vertices. Or just add Mirror modifier to the mesh and re-mirror it again

Comment: Looks like you should be using a *Mirror* modifier